# How to read data from lucene file store in aws s3 using java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, lucene

I have lucene files in amazon AWS S3 i.e .cfs,.gen etc files. How can I read data from those files, I am using java.

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can't, this must be a local file system. Transfer those files to you machine and open them.

You can try using [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) but the risk is on you. Why bother?